# Get double value from currency frormatted string

Tags: java, android, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I'm using `NumberFormat` in my app to get the currency formatted Strings. Like if a user inputs **12.25** in the field then it will be changed to **$12.25** based on locale. Here the Locale is **en-US**. 
Now I want to get the 12.25 value as double form the formatted string.
To do that I have used:

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().parse("$12.25").doubleValue();
```

Above line giving me the result of 12.25 which is my requirement. But suppose a user changed his locale to something else **en-UK**. Now for that locale above statement is giving me parseException. Because for the locale **en-UK**, currency string **$12.25** is not parsable.

So is there any way to get the double value from currency formatted string irrespective of what the locale is?

Comment: You can split the fist char (locale currency symbol). idk if it's what you want.

Comment: Hopefully, every user pays the same price in your store depending on locale. €12.25 is more than $12.25 ^^

Comment: First of all I guess you should not hardcode for only one Locale.... Then, for whatever Locale you code in you source, a switch case may help you to do what you want...

Comment: @AntonioI can split the first char. But the problem is for the `Brazilian Portuguese` the currency symbol is `R$` and `comma(,)` is used as a decimal separator.

Comment: Do you want to keep state in the webpage? That is not a good idea.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sorry, I didn't get your point.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal In that case, please explain why you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: [Dont use `double` for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know either the below solution is perfect or not but it is working according to my requirement.

```
try {
    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().parse(currency).doubleValue();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // Currency string is not parsable
    // might be different locale
    String cleanString = currency.replaceAll("\\D", "");
    try {
        double money = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
        return money / 100;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
new Double(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().parse("$12.25").doubleValue());
```

and also you could use

`Double.valueOf()` creates a Double object so .doubleValue() should not be necessary.

also `Double.parseDouble(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().parse("$12.25"));`

could work

Comment: thanks for your response. But my question is parsing doesn't work if the user locale and currency formatted string locale are not matched. So I need a solution to that.

Comment: you could just do a string for only the locale with the currency and attach it to the value

Comment: @DeepakGoyal Yup...You can't hardcode only en-US Locale and expect it to work with en-UK Locale

Comment: @JasonKrs Exactly, this is my requirement.

Comment: @DeepakGoyal I guess programmatically speaking, you gotta adapt your code to your requirements.... If you program is going to be used is 5 different Locale, then I advise you SWITCH CASE the heck out of it ;-)

Comment: @DeepakGoyal unless you always split the first character and do your work just like Antonio said in the first command

Comment: @JasonKrs Some currencies have two chars like `R$` and in this currency, the comma is used for decimal and dot is used for separation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little algorithm that may help you :

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

        String cash = "R$1,000.75"; //The loop below will work for ANY currency as long as it does not start with a digit
        boolean continueLoop = true;

                char[] cashArray = cash.toCharArray();      

        int cpt = 0;

                while(continueLoop){
                    try  
                    {  
                        double d = Double.parseDouble(cashArray[cpt]+"");  
                        continueLoop = false;
                    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){  
                        cpt += 1;  
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(cpt);

                //From here you can do whatever you want....

                String extracted = cash.substring(cpt);

                NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US); //YOUR REQUIREMENTS !!!! lol
                try {
                    Number youValue = format.parse(extracted);
                    System.out.println(youValue.doubleValue());
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    //handle your parse error here
                }

    }
```

You should get as result here in the output:

2

1000.75